# How to use config with ckeditor and jeditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jeditable

I use jeditable : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
with the ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/

I found a plugin that works fine : http://blog.amps211.com/this-is-me-professing-my-love-for-jquery-and-how-i-got-ckeditor-working-with-jeditable/

But I have a problem, I can't add a customConfig.

My code :

```
var config = {
          toolbar: [
            ['Source'],['ShowBlocks'],
            ['PasteText'],
            ['Image','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
            '/',
            ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Superscript','Format'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link','Unlink']
          ],
          toolbarStartupExpanded: true,
          toolbarCanCollapse: false,
          toolbarLocation: 'top',
          startupShowBorders: false,
          forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
          skin: 'office2003',
          filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'mylinkbrowse',
          filebrowserUploadUrl : 'mylinkupload',
          resize_enabled: 'true',
          resize_dir: 'vertical',
          height: '300px',
          width: '100%',
          uiColor: '#123456',
          language: 'en'
        }

 $('.editreply').click(function(){
          var editor = $(this).parent().find('.replyeditor');

          editor.editable('mylink',{
            type:'ckeditor',
            cancel:'Cancel',
            submit: 'OK',
            rows:3,
            onblur: 'ignore'                
          }); // END OF EDITABLE
          CKEDITOR.replace(editor.find("textarea"),{customConfig:config});
          editor.click();
          //alert(editor.attr('id'));

        }); // ENF editreply CLICK
```

The aim is to click on edit button to render the ckeditor. I add editor.click() to simulate the click.

How can pass the config to the ckeditor?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think that CKEditor function is looking for a URL to the config, not the config itself.  e.g. CKEDITOR.replace( 'myfiled', { customConfig : '/myconfig.js' } );

I'm pretty sure if you update "config.js", it will be used during every init.  (I don't use that approach)

Because I have a simple setup (all my editors use the same config) I update the base CKEditor first...

```
function initializeCKEditor() { 

var customToolBar =
    [
        ['LocalSave','NewPage','-','Templates'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'Scayt'],
        ['Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat','-','About','Preview'],
        ['Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', ...];

    //Enable Spell as you Type 
CKEDITOR.config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'localSave'; 
    CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = customToolBar;
```

then as needed i create/destroy editor instances

```
    function initializeEditor(orientation) {
    //ckeditor config 
var ckeditor_config = {
        sharedSpaces : {
            top : 'editor-toolbar'
        },
        width : (scrnWidth+ckeditor_width_border),
        height: scrnHieght};

//this is why we're here
$('.editor').ckeditor(ckeditor_config);
```

I hope that helps.  I don't see any reason why you can't use the same approach.  If you set the base CKEditior once, I perceive you'll have less overhead during instance creation but never bench marked.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to send the config from jEditable via the "ckeditor"-parameter. This is how mine config looks and it works great.

```
$(".editable_textarea").editable("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>", { 
    indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
    type   : 'ckeditor',
    submitdata: { _method: "post" },
    select : true,
    submit : 'OK',
    cancel : 'cancel',
    cssclass : "editable",
    onblur: "ignore",
    ckeditor : {
    toolbar:
    [
    ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Format', 'Styles', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'HorizontalRule', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'Image', '-', 'Maximize'],
    ['UIColor']
    ],
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: baseUrl + 'admin/assets/?target=ckeditor',
    contentsCss : baseUrl + 'media/css/custom_styles.css',
    stylesSet : []
    }
    });
```